# a if statement only works with certain values

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, comparison

im programming a physical (Monte carlo spin magnetic field-) simulation in c and encountered a kind of weird problem. 
An if statement only works for a certain value of one variable. what im trying to do is that i have a variable (bh, the external magnetic field) that has a certain initial value. i continue to decrease it until it hits -bh within 10 steps, then it should start increasing until it hits +bh again and so on until the iteration is over.
this works fine for bh=.3, but if i set it to .1, .2 or 1 it doesnt work. it starts decreasing but doesnt stop until the simulation is over. there is no other value in my program that equals .3!

im not sure what to include, since the main program is a bit longer. but the code fragments are (without the main loop, but including debug echos):

```
 float bh;  float bmax;
 bh=.3; bmax=bh;

if (bup==1) {
     printf("BUP=1, BFeld = %.2f\n",bh);
     bh = bh + bmax/10;
     if (bh == bmax) { bup=0; }
}
if (bup==0) {
    printf("BUP=0, BFeld = %.2f, %.2f = bmin\n",bh,-bmax);
    bh = bh - bmax/10;
    if (bh == -bmax) { bup=1; }
}
```

what i get in terms of debug output is for bh=.3

```
[...]
BUP=0, BFeld = -0.24, -0.30 = bmin
BUP=0, BFeld = -0.27, -0.30 = bmin
BUP=1, BFeld = -0.30
BUP=1, BFeld = -0.27
BUP=1, BFeld = -0.24
[...]
```

But when i set bh to 1, i get

```
[...]
BUP=0, BFeld = -0.80, -1.00 = bmin
BUP=0, BFeld = -0.90, -1.00 = bmin
BUP=0, BFeld = -1.00, -1.00 = bmin
BUP=0, BFeld = -1.10, -1.00 = bmin
BUP=0, BFeld = -1.20, -1.00 = bmin
BUP=0, BFeld = -1.30, -1.00 = bmin
[...]
```

so my debug output even gives me the line "...-1.00, -1.00...", but somehow c thinks theyre not equal "enough" to set bup to 1. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Don't compare floats for equality because of the internal rounding.

Comment: Please read the comments under my answer carefully, they are giving some really helpful advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (bh == bmax) { bup=1; }
```

Using `==` to compare floating point number usually results not what you expected because of  rounding.

Define `EPSILON` as some reasonable small value and compare floating point numbers like this:

```
if (fabs(bh - bmax) < EPSILON)
```

Comment: ah okay, so i have to use double and then it should work? gonna try that, thanks!

Comment: Using a double will not help. Floats and doubles are finite approximations to real numbers and do not have infinite precision.

Comment: @Nicouh Not really, using `double` leads to similar problem, you should compare them like `if (fabs(bh - bmax) < EPSILON` and define `EPSILON` as some reasonable small value.

Comment: This is the wrong solution. The appropriate comparison is simply `>=` or `<=` for OP's problem.

Comment: C defines `FLT_EPSILON` and `DBL_EPSILON` in float.h that you can use for the comparison.

Comment: The `EPSILON` trick makes sense only in some contexts. What you really want is a comparison that tests whether two values would have been mathematically equal if the computations that produced them had been done in infinite precision, and that depends on the computations. For small values, an absolute `EPSILON` can easily give you false positives (consider comparing two values that happen to be `EPSILON` and `EPSILON/100.0`). For large values, it can give you false negatives. Testing the ratio *might* make more sense, but again, it depends heavily on the computations that produced the results.

Comment: @greatwolf Blindly using `FLT_EPSILON` and `DBL_EPSILON` as the constant for a `fabs(bh - bmax) < EPSILON` kind of comparison is doubly wrong. If you are going to write `fabs(bh - bmax) < EPSILON` it should be because you understand that it is what you need, and if you understand that you can determine the right constant. In addition, `fabs(bh - bmax) < DBL_EPSILON` is **STRICTLY EQUIVALENT** to `bh == bmax` if either variable's magnitude is above 2.

Answer (score 3):

You should never test for equality with floating point variables. You need to test within some tolerance. For example:

```
#define EPSILON (0.000001)
if (fabs(bh - bmax) < EPSILON)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should not compare floating points with `==` because that operator seraches for an exact match.

Even though your numbers look pretty simple when expressed in decimal notation (±.3, and steps of ±.03), when translated to the internal binary representation od FP numbers, they cause an endless repeated bit pattern (analogous to repeated decimals).  Since FP numbers have a limited size, the exceeding bits are either truncated or rounded, but in either case, their successive accumulation might increase is likely to introduce growing devations from the exact representation of the expected numbers.